# compilation error for avx512, is it a GCC issue?

Tags: c, gcc, x86, avx512

I am trying to compile the following code with AVX512 intrinsic, but gives me the compile error.

```
#include <immintrin.h>

static inline __attribute__((always_inline)) void
mov64(uint8_t *dst, const uint8_t *src)
{
        __m512i zmm0;

        zmm0 = _mm512_load_si512((const void *)src);
        _mm512_store_si512((void *)dst, zmm0);
}
```

The compilation error:

```
gcc -D_GNU_SOURCE -DINFO_LOG_DEBUG --std=c99 -march=native -O3 -DNDEBUG -m64 -mtune=native -Werror -Wall -Wundef -Wpointer-arith -Wstrict-prototypes -Wnested-externs -fomit-frame-pointer -DTRANSPORT_CONFIG_OPT_HDR='<ci/internal/transport_config_opt_extra.h>'  -c src/main.c -o obj/main.o 
src/main.c: In function ‘mov64’:
src/main.c:15:9: error: unknown type name ‘__m512i’
         __m512i zmm0;
         ^
src/main.c:17:9: error: implicit declaration of function ‘_mm512_load_si512’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
         zmm0 = _mm512_load_si512((const void *)src);
         ^
src/main.c:17:9: error: nested extern declaration of ‘_mm512_load_si512’ [-Werror=nested-externs]
src/main.c:18:9: error: implicit declaration of function ‘_mm512_store_si512’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
         _mm512_store_si512((void *)dst, zmm0);
         ^
src/main.c:18:9: error: nested extern declaration of ‘_mm512_store_si512’ [-Werror=nested-externs]
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

In addition, if I add -march=native,avx512f or -mavx512f or -march=skylake-avx512, it gives the following error:

```
src/main.c:1:0: error: bad value (skylake-avx512) for -march= switch
```

My GCC version is 4.8.5 20150623 and CPU is "Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6154". What should I do to overcome this problem? Thanks in advance..

Comment: Was your GCC configured (built) to know about the AVX512 intrinsics?  If not, that's why — and your testing with the extra options like `-mavx512f` strongly suggest that's the problem.  You'll probably need to install a new version (build) of GCC; you may need to download source to build it.  GCC 4.8.x is pretty ancient; it may well not support the new chip you're using.

Comment: Skylake AVX-512 extensions are supported starting with gcc 6.1. See: https://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/gcc-6/changes.html.

Comment: Thanks, I upgraded my GCC to 9.1 and it is working now

Comment: Side note: `-D_GNU_SOURCE` combined with `--std=c99` seems pretty odd to me.  Is that achieving something different for you than replacing them both with `--std=gnu99` would do?

Comment: -D_GNU_SOURCE is for CPU_ZERO, CPU_SET, etc..

Comment: @JohnBollinger `-std=gnu99` doesn't automatically set `_GNU_SOURCE`. It just enables certain extensions in the compiler itself.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler How could one determine in retrospect whether the GCC has been built to know about AVX512? I am thinking about GCC versions 6.1+ that support AVX521 instruction sets, at least nominally.

Answer (score 4):

GCC 4.8 does not support any of the AVX-512 variants. If this is the system compiler from Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7, you can use a new GCC version from [Red Hat Developer Toolset](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_developer_toolset/), which provides support for later CPU features. (DTS is also available for CentOS.)

Comment: When using new instruction sets, always a good idea to use the newest stable compiler you can.  You want the compiler to make *efficient* code (that's the whole point of using AVX512), and more recent GCC has had more time to update tuning / code-gen decisions after CPUs supporting AVX512 were available to test on.  (This is also why you should always use `-march=native` or `-march=skylake-avx512` whenever possible instead of just `-mavx512f`).  Currently gcc8 is a good choice, and gcc9.1 is still pretty new.

Comment: Even though gcc4.9 introduced AVX512 support, it was released before either KNL Xeon Phi or Skylake-AVX512 so nobody could test it for performance tuning on either of the microarchitectures that can run AVX512 code.  So even if you have that, still upgrade to newer GCC if you can, preferably 8.x at least for more efficient stack-alignment in functions using wide vectors.